# How to use the add tag in django admin templates

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-admin

in django admin `change_list_results.html` there is a part which is responsible  for the items that get registered for a model in the screen

```
{% for item in result %}
  {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Now I wanted to add something to the first of every `item`, I know if it was in pagination, I could do `add:paginator.page.start_index`

but in this case, there is no `start_index` key for `item`, or `result` :

`{{ forloop.counter|add:item.start_index }}` or

`{{ forloop.counter|add:result.start_index }}`

returns

```
Failed lookup for key [start_index] in '<td class="action-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="_selected_action" value="705" class="action-select"></td>'
```

**So what should I do to add something to the listview of an item in django admin using the template(in the rendering stage)?**

Comment: Normally this is *not* something that belongs to the template, but to the view: a view implements business logic, the template implements rendering logic.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you give me a clue about what to do/what to look for ?, I previously tried adding row numbers to objects through `admin.py`, but the results were not proper, It easily would've get unordered in production, and now that I'm trying to do it through the template and frontend, I can't find a way to attach that to the objects.